# How to run `svn log` from Jenkins while protecting credentials?

Tags: security, svn, jenkins, credentials, statsvn

I'm generating StatSvn reports with Jenkins, and it requires the `svn log`. While Jenkins protects my SVN credentials from being saved as plain text, I could only make it securely checkout my repository, not generate the log. To `svn log` I must type my credentials in the batch command leaving them unprotected.

How to protect them?

Comment: generally `svn log` does not require credentials. do not see why jenkins has to ask for it.

Comment: Seems like it's a Jenkins bug https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-3338

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it's a Jenkins bug http://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-3338